# Parse.com data showing wrong info

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this code snippet and if I click on one set of data in a table view it will tell me what data set I picked:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSLog(@"cell Tapped");
PFObject *tempObject = [colorsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

_infoDetailLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"name"];
[self animateDetailView];
NSLog(@"%@", tempObject.objectId);
}
```

The only problem is it's showing me the data one row below the one I clicked. It will also not recognise the first click, so I have to click another one after my first click to make it select a row.

Comment: my mistake sorry im working on loads of stuff today my heads full of numbers ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
                                             ^^^
```

Your delegate method fires when you *de*select the row. That is: click on row 1, then click on row 2, you'll get notified that row 1 has been deselected.

You probably want `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: No problem! I've made the same mistake before, which is why I saw it.